# I'm developing in Android Studio, When I run my app on my S4 2 copies are created on my phone

Tags: android, android-studio

My project currently has just two classes and when I run the project on my phone two apps are created. The first app runs the entire project and the second app only runs one class(The class that isn't my Main). Has anyone encountered this bug before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have multiple activities defined as launcher activities in your manifest, like so:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AnotherActivity">
        <!-- creates a second "app" when deploying -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

That would create two apps on your phone.

Comment: This is exactly what's wrong, been going though my code for hours, never saw it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 'Jaap Van Hengstum' is correct.
If you want only one entry point for your application, then only one activity should have below intent filter.

```
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Remove if you have multiple entry of it in your manifest file.